# Duplicating elements in a list x number of times

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to duplicate each element individually right after each other while preserving the order. For example the function would look like

```
def duplicate(testList, n)
    for i in l:
        ll.append(i)
        ll.append(i)
```

`testList` being the input list and `n` being the number of times you duplicate each element within. With what I came up with I can't loop it for a certain number of times. Not sure how to do it.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: `ll.extend([i] * n)` will also work

Answer (score 4):

how bout

```
def n_times(v,n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield v

[i for j in testList for i in n_times(j,2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add second loop which will iterate n times adding your values. However I advice you to learn generators as well and do it on one line like Joran Beasley suggested.

```
def duplicate(testList, n)
    for i in l:
        for x in range(n):
            ll.append(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your are looking for a result like [Ashwini Chaudhary described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026100/duplicating-elements-in-a-list-x-number-of-times/33026260#comment53874851_33026260), you can go like this:

```
from itertools import chain  # Hinted by Ashwini Chaudhary

def repeat(lst, n):
    return list(chain(*zip(*[x for _ in range(n)])))

>>> repeat([1, 2, 3], 3)
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Otherwise, if you are looking for just repeating the list `n` times, as a general solution you could go with the following function:

```
def repeat(lst, n):
    result = []
    for _ in range(n):
        result += lst[:]
    return result

>>> repeat([1, 2, 3], 2)
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

However, *if the elements are guaranteed to be immutable objects*, there is a pretty nice way for a list to do that in Python:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] * 2
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This is basically `lst * n`, but I don't think that's what OP is asking here: `repeat([1, 2, 3], 2)` --> `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`.

Comment: Thanks, I suspect that, waiting for a reply from the OP.

Comment: Why `zip()`? How about: `for el in lst: result += [el] * n`. And lastly what's `x` there?

Comment: Using `zip` or `izip` we can do something like this though: `list(chain.from_iterable(izip(*[[1, 2, 3, 4]] * 3)))`. Considering we are dealing with immutable objects.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the bug :) good point about `[el] * n`, the problem to do that is that if `el` is a mutable object, it will not be copied, rather its reference will be copied across the list.

Comment: Excellent!! chain is what I have obviously missed .

Answer (score 3):

As a one-liner:

```
def n_plicate(testList, n):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, map(lambda x: [x]*n, testList))
```

or a little bit easier to read and faster:

```
    return [tm for sblst in [[x]*n for x in testList] for tm in sblst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Long and Easier, without any imports,

```
    def duplicate(listt,number):
        """Input a list and a num evry vlue in the list is replctd by Num of times """
        temp=[]
        for i in listt:
              temp.append(i*number)
       output=[]
       for j in temp:
              output.extend(list(j))
       return output
```